# Fragment backstack and replace

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentmanager

I have 2 fragments `A` and `B`. I added fragment `B` from fragment `A` `(A->B)` with `addToBackStack()`. Now when I am in fragment `B` and press back everything is OK and return to the `A`.

But when I am in fragment `C` I want to display fragment `B` if it is **existed** in fragment manager by checking `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("");` then I `replace` this fragment.

The problem is the `backstack` not work in this situation. I mean whenever I press back the fragment A is **not** shown. How can I preserve that `backstack` too?

Comment: Have you added B to backstack ?

Comment: Does your onBackPressed() call super method?

Comment: @VivekMishra yes

Comment: @underoid yes I call.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code i am using

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.popBackStack(fragment.toString(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            FragmentTransaction tx = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            Log.v("on calling fragment", fragment + "==" + fragment.toString());
            tx.replace(R.id.fl_main, fragment).addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
```

This give different particular backstack
 string to each fragment being replaced.